# Count the no of columns with same value in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a database MySQL table as following

| Id | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | value1 | value1 | value2 |
| Second | value2 | value1 | value2 |

I want to retrieve the count of value1 for the row with id First example table as follows

| Id | COUNT(value1) |
| --- | --- |
| First | 2 |

I searched on google but found posts only regarding counting in one specific column.
Can anyone help me with the SQL query for retrieving the above type.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `case` expression to determine for each column whether to count it or not e.g.

```
select
    case when Column1 = 'value1' then 1 else 0 end
    + case when Column2 = 'value1' then 1 else 0 end
    -- ...
from MyTable
where id = 'first'
```

Comment: I pretty much understand what you are trying to convey but can you please provide me the actual query for the above mentioned table.